# How to use a band scale to push the chart to the edges

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a way to make the parallel coordinates go all the way to the edges and then equally space the "dimensions" between that? I thought that the `x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(1)` was the culprit here but it appears that something else is in play. I would really appreciate if someone helped me out here.

[image]

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20},
                    width = d3.select(ele[0])._groups[0][0].offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
                    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                // set the height based on the calculations above
                svg.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

                var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(1),
                    y = {},
                    dragging = {},
                    selected;

                var line = d3.line(),
                    background,
                    foreground,
                    extents;

                x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) {
                    if(d === "name") {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return y[d] = d3.scaleLinear()
                        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(p) {
                            return +p[d]; }))
                        .range([height, 0]);
                }));

                extents = dimensions.map(function(p) { return [0,0]; });

                // Add grey background lines for context.
                background = svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "background")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + margin.top + ")")
                    .selectAll("path")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("path")
                    .attr("d", path);

                // Add blue foreground lines for focus.
                foreground = svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "foreground")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + margin.top + ")")
                    .selectAll("path")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("path")
                    .attr("d", path);

                // Add a group element for each dimension.
                var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
                    .data(dimensions)
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "dimension")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {  return "translate(" + x(d) + ")"; })
                    .call(d3.drag()
                        .subject(function(d) { return {x: x(d)}; })
                        .on("start", function(d) {
                            dragging[d] = x(d);
                            background.attr("visibility", "hidden");
                        })
                        .on("drag", function(d) {
                            dragging[d] = Math.min(width, Math.max(0, d3.event.x));
                            foreground.attr("d", path);
                            dimensions.sort(function(a, b) { return position(a) - position(b); });
                            x.domain(dimensions);
                            g.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + position(d) + ")"; })
                        })
                        .on("end", function(d) {
                            delete dragging[d];
                            transition(d3.select(this)).attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d) + ")");
                            transition(foreground).attr("d", path);
                            background
                                .attr("d", path)
                                .transition()
                                .delay(500)
                                .duration(0)
                                .attr("visibility", null);
                        }));

                // Add an axis and title.
                g.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .each(function(d) {  d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft(y[d]));})
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + margin.top + ")")
                    .append("text")
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("y", -9)
                    .text(function(d) { return d; });

                // Add and store a brush for each axis.
                g.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "brush")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + margin.top + ")")
                    .each(function(d) {
                        d3.select(this)
                            .call(y[d].brush = d3.brushY().extent([[-8, 0], [8,height]])
                                .on("brush start", brushstart)
                                .on("brush", brush_parallel_chart));
                    })
                    .selectAll("rect")
                    .attr("x", -8)
                    .attr("width", 16);

                function position(d) {
                    var v = dragging[d];
                    return v === null || v === undefined ? x(d) : v;
                }

                function transition(g) {
                    return g.transition().duration(500);
                }

                // Returns the path for a given data point.
                function path(d) {
                    return line(dimensions.map(function(p) {
                        return [position(p), y[p](d[p])];
                    }));
                }

                function brushstart() {
                    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                }

                function within(d, extent){
                    return extent[1] <= d && d <= extent[0];
                }

                // Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
                function brush_parallel_chart() {
                    for(var i = 0; i < dimensions.length; ++i){
                        if(d3.event.target === y[dimensions[i]].brush) {
                            extents[i] = d3.event.selection.map(y[dimensions[i]].invert,y[dimensions[i]]);
                        }
                    }

                    foreground.style("display", function(d) {
                        return dimensions.every(function(p, i) {
                            if(extents[i][0]===0 && extents[i][1]===0) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            return within(d[p], extents[i])
                        }) ? null : "none";
                    });

                    selected = data.filter(function(item){
                        if(dimensions.every(function(dim, index){
                                if(extents[index][0]===0 && extents[index][1]===0) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                return within(item[dim], extents[index]);
                            })){
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                    scope.onBrush({item: selected});
                }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The band scale is the wrong tool for this dataviz.

The problem is that a band scale has an associated bandwidth. So, when you use a band scale, it will return the left margin of the respective bandwidth (or, in other words, the left margin of the "step"):

[image]

Look at the values returned by a band scale using 5 values and a range going from `0` to `100`:

```js
var data = "abcde".split("")
var s = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data)
  .range([0, 100]);

data.forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(s(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

If you set the padding to 1 it will help to reduce the bandwidth, but not that much (more on that below):

```js
var data = "abcde".split("")
var s = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data)
  .range([0, 100])
  .padding(1);

data.forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(s(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**Solution**:

Use a point scale instead. Point scales have no bandwidth:

[image]

Here is the demo, look at the values:

```js
var data = "abcde".split("")
var s = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(data)
  .range([0, 100]);

data.forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(s(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Regarding the padding, since I said *"more on that below"*: you almost got it right! The problem is that `padding` is ...

> ... a convenience method for setting the inner and outer padding to the same padding value.

So, it sets both the inner and the outer padding. If you used `paddingInner(1)` and `paddingOuter(0)` you would get the same result of a point scale:

```js
var data = "abcde".split("")
var s = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data)
  .range([0, 100])
  .paddingInner(1)
  .paddingOuter(0);

data.forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(s(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is awesome. That makes perfect sense. I knew it had to be something with the bands. My initial instinct was to set the `outerPadding()` to 0 but without setting `innerPadding()` it still didn't behave correctly. Thank you for clarifying that!

Answer (score -2):

Try changing `margin` to:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 10, left: 0},
```

in the first line. The margin is how much space is around the diagram. This should also change the value of `width`, which uses the margin in its declaration. Since width will increase, the x scale should change, making the "dimensions" equally spaced but further apart from one another.

Comment: As you can see my current setting for the right margin is 10px. That's hardly anywhere near the offset that is being applied. The width of the SVG object is set to 100% so it's the size of the div frame it sits in. The `width` value is set to width of div - margin.left - margin.right so it's only smaller by 30px yet my chart is not taking up that much space. I am guessing the issue is with the RangeRound() and how the intervals are set, or how the dimensions are being offset.